# Merge 7 rows with identical cells in CSV with c#

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I have converted an xml file to csv file base on a specific decendant.
This is the result that i have obtain [csv file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy999.jpg)

In the file i have 3 products and each product take upto 7 lines, i wish to merge all the details as per product since many cells value are identical.

I want my result to be as follow [expected result of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o4w8.jpg)

How can i do that in c#?

Note that my number of columns remains the same

Comment: There is no such thing as cells or merging with CSV files. These are just text files. How they are displayed is entirely up to the application that displays them. *Nothing* says that the file should have the same number of fields in each line.

Comment: If you want columns and merged cells, create an Excel file with a library like [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). It's as simple as callling `sheet.LoadFromCollection(orders)` or `sheet.LoadFromDataTable(ordersTable)`

Comment: More over, what have you tried so far? You dont seem to have shown us where you failed

Comment: @BugFinder what the OP asks is simply impossible with CSVs, ie Plain Old Text Files - if a row has fewer fields than the previous one, which of the fields is merged? Are *any* of them merged, or is the last field missing?

Comment: I will suggest to use library like Epplus to manipulate csv. Its very simple to use.

Comment: I have tried some code that i got while searching but it was not working out.I will try to do some research on the Epplus. Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq to combine the related rows as you requested.

Lets say, you have object defined to represent each CSV row as below (for clarify, mentioned few columns only)

```
public class Item
{
    public string szItemId { get; set; }
    public string szName { get; set; }
    public string lRetailStoreID { get; set; }
    public string szDesc { get; set; }
}
```

Now the hard part to merge them using Linq projection query as below

```
var recs =  p.Where(r => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.szItemId)).GroupBy(r => r.szItemId)
    .Select(g => new {
    szItemId = g.Key,
    szName = g.Where(i1 => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i1.szName)).Select(i1 => i1.szName).FirstOrDefault(),
    lRetailStoreID = g.Where(i1 => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i1.lRetailStoreID)).Select(i1 => i1.lRetailStoreID).FirstOrDefault(),
    szDesc = g.Where(i1 => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i1.szDesc)).Select(i1 => i1.szDesc).FirstOrDefault()
});
```

The above query gives you merged rows from your input csv file. Now you can iterate and write them to CSV.

Hope this helps.

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source framework, you can read and write CSV file quickly with few lines of code as below

```
using (var p = new ChoCSVReader("mergeinput.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
{
    var recs = p.Where(r => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.szItemId)).GroupBy(r => r.szItemId)
        .Select(g => new {
            szItemId = g.Key,
            szName = g.Where(i1 => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i1.szName)).Select(i1 => i1.szName).FirstOrDefault(),
            lRetailStoreID = g.Where(i1 => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i1.lRetailStoreID)).Select(i1 => i1.lRetailStoreID).FirstOrDefault(),
            szDesc = g.Where(i1 => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i1.szDesc)).Select(i1 => i1.szDesc).FirstOrDefault()
        });

    using (var o = new ChoCSVWriter("mergeoutput.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
    {
        o.Write(recs);
    }
}
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library